# How to set a tab bar item's title from a child view controller in interface builder?

Tags: interface-builder, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem

I know programmatically I can set a child view controller's title and it will updated its related tab bar item's title but how do I set that up in Interface Builder?

Answer (score 0):

Interface Builder doesn't have an exposed property for a view controllers title but it does allow you to set properties in the "User Defined Runtime Attributes" section under Identity Inspector tab. Just set the key path to `title`, type to `String`, and Value to your desired title. Also check out Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/recipes/xcode_help-interface_builder/Chapters/AddUserDefinedRuntimeAttributes.html). Or check out this blog for a visual walkthrough: http://ios-blog.co.uk/tutorials/user-defined-runtime-attributes/

You can also have finer grain control by setting these different properties:

```
self.navigationItem.title = @"my title"; //sets navigation bar title.

self.tabBarItem.title = @"my title"; //sets tab bar title.

self.title = @"my title"; //sets both of these.
```